# Dask read_csv from io.bytesIO

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, dask

im trying to read a csv storage in an io.bytesIO with dask. thats is possible?

```
    blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.credentials['connection_string'])
    blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_client(container=      self.credentials['container_name'],blob=filename)
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    download_stream.download_to_stream(stream)
    stream.seek(0)
    df = dd.read_csv(stream.getvalue().decode().split('\n'))
```

it seems that the first parameter should be an url path. But i had to take the csv from the io.bytesIO(the variable stream). is there a way to to this without save the file in the local?
Im creating an ETL so the credentials ever is going to change.So that is the reason why im trying to do it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to leverage the `delayed` and `pandas` (which can read from `io`), roughly like this:

```py
from dask import delayed
from dask.dataframe import from_delayed
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

@delayed
def io_to_pandas(stream):
   ... # any necessary logic
   df = read_csv(stream.getvalue())
   return df

# specify the expected data shape (can also specify dtypes)
meta = DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

ddf = from_delayed(io_to_pandas(stream), meta=meta)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly using standard dask dataframe syntax if you wish - answer below. However, I believe you are loading from azure blob, so you can likely do something like the following and not need to copy bytes things around

```
df = dd.read_csv("az://{container}/{file}", storage_options=credentials_stuff)
```

---

The fsspec implementation MemoryFileSystem ("memory") uses a subclass of io.BytesIO as its internal implementation. Here is one way to do it

```
import fsspec
fsspec.filesystem("memory").pipe("data", stream.read())
df = dd.read_csv("memory://data")
```